# PHP integer variable in mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, variables, integer

I'm trying to input a PHP variable (in this case $beg) into a mySQL query but it returns an empty array result. The type of the field in the database is an integer. When I type in an actual value instead of the variable I get the correct result. What's wrong?

```
    $beg = time()-5000;
    settype($beg, "integer");

    $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM records WHERE time>=$beg ORDER BY time ASC');

    $statusdata = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    array_push($statusdata, $row["status"]);
    }
```

Comment: you shouldn't be mixing php and mysql time values. there's subtle race conditions that can occurl. mysql is perfectly capable of doing its own date math: `where time >= unix_timestamp(now() - interval 5000 second)`

Comment: For that I would set the field as a timestamp in the DB right?

Comment: you're already going integer comparisons, so I'm assuming the `time` field is an int. if it's a datetime, then you don't need the timestamp stuff at all. `time >= now() - interval 5000 second`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you use double quotes when using $variables inside the string.

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE time>= $beg ORDER BY time ASC");
```

Comment: Or better, use string concatenation. Or better still, don't use `mysql_*` function and use prepared queries instead

Answer (score 2):

You should use prepared statements instead of mysql_query.

```
$beg = time()-5000;
settype($beg, "integer");

$db = new mysqli("host","user","pw","database");
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT status FROM records WHERE time>=? ORDER BY time ASC");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $beg);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($status);

$statusdata = array();
while($stmt->fetch())
{
  array_push($statusdata, $status);
}

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: I'm not quite there yet still learning the basics but thanks, really nice example.

Comment: Using prepared statements prevents you from `SQL injections` that you can face using mysql_query which is deprecated. You should use pdo or mysqli instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM records WHERE time>=$beg ORDER BY time ASC");
```

You must use double quote strings to put variables.

Answer (score 0):

Change your query

```
$result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM records WHERE time >= $beg ORDER BY time ASC ");
```

You cannot use variable inside single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try this method, I use a lot:

```
$beg = time() - 5000;
$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE time >= '%o' ORDER BY %s ASC", "records", $beg, "time");
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

remeber, time() result is Integer, you don't need set him in to an Integer